# Enum in viewmodel is not triggering refresh in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, enums

I've got a ViewModel which conforms the `ObservableObject` protocol.

This ViewModel holds a enum variable.

```
class DeviceViewModel:ObservableObject {
    
    enum ConnectionState: Equatable, CaseIterable {
        case NoConnected
        case Connected
    }
    
    @Published var connectionState: ConnectionState = .NoConnected
    
}
```

I also got a simple view that it will change the text depending of that enum:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let viewModel: DeviceViewModel

    var body: some View {
        if viewModel.connectionState != .NoConnected {
            Text("connected")
        } else {
            Text("No connected")
        }
    }
}
```

I've noticed that if the enum `connectionState` changes it won't trigger the view to refresh.

To test this I've added a init method in the ViewModel with the following `asyncAfter`:

```
    init() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else {
                return
            }

            self.connectionState = .Connected
            print("self.connectionState: \(self.connectionState)")
        }
    }
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: Use `@ObservedObject var viewModel: DeviceViewModel` or `@StateObject var viewModel: DeviceViewModel` in your view

Answer (score 1):

The view needs to observe the changes in order to refresh:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject let viewModel: DeviceViewModel
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use @StateObject to declare your viewModel.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = DeviceViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        if viewModel.connectionState != .NoConnected {
            Text("connected")
        } else {
            Text("No connected")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Never use `@StateObject` to declare a view model. The model is an external dependency which should be passed to the view observed via `@ObservedObject`.
`@StateObject` (for reference types) and `@State` (for value types) are designed for internal state of the view.